# How to create a new File with full path in Qt?

Tags: qt, file, qfile

I am a Qt beginner and just got stuck with the problem. I am looking for a file `SomePath/NewDirectoryA/NewFile.kml` (`NewFile.kml` will be the only file in `NewDirectoryA`, having this directory just to maintain semantics in the project).

If `SomePath/NewDirectoryA/NewFile.kml` exists then I will use it in my code and if it doesn't exist then I have to create it. If this File doesn't exist then this directory also doesn't exist in `SomePath`. So If only I have to create a file I can use QFile and open it in ReadWrite or WriteOnly mode.

But the problem is I have to create the file with the directory itself.
I tried with `QFile` with file name `SomePath/NewDirectoryA/NewFile.kml` but it didn't worked.

Please suggest me a way in which I can create a new file (NewFile.kml) in a new directory (NewDirectorA) at  a given location (SomePath).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> **bool [QFile::open](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) ( OpenMode  mode )   [virtual]**
>
> [...]
>
> Note: In WriteOnly or ReadWrite mode,
>   if the relevant file does not already
>   exist, this function will try to
>   create a new file before opening it.

Qt's caveat for file creation

> [**Platform Specific Issues**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#platform-specific-issues)
>
> File permissions are handled differently on Unix-like systems and
>   Windows. In a non writable directory on Unix-like systems, files
>   cannot be created. This is not always the case on Windows, where, for
>   instance, the 'My Documents' directory usually is not writable, but it
>   is still possible to create files in it.

Directories are created with

> **bool
>   [QDir::mkdir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#mkdir) 
>   ( const QString & dirName  ) const**
>
> Creates a sub-directory called
>   dirName.

and

> **bool [QDir::mkpath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#mkpath)
>   ( const QString & dirPath  ) const**
>
> Creates the directory path dirPath.
>
> The function will create all parent
>   directories necessary to create the
>   directory.

Comment: can't I create a file with all necessary parent directories ?

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK it is not possible to create the file and the directory directly with `QFile`. You have to first create the directory ([`QDir::mkpath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath) will create the full path) and then the file ([`QFile::open`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open)).

```
QString path("SomePath/NewDirectoryA/");
QDir dir; // Initialize to the desired dir if 'path' is relative
          // By default the program's working directory "." is used.

// We create the directory if needed
if (!dir.exists(path))
    dir.mkpath(path); // You can check the success if needed

QFile file(path + "NewFile.kml");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); // Or QIODevice::ReadWrite
```