# Make a text file for Qt

Tags: qt, file

I can make a file and make my Qt project read and write to it .

But How can I make it create it's own text file for the first time then it writes and reads from and to it later for example i want it to write and read to and from this directory C:\Users\Administrator\Documents .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024382/how-to-create-a-new-file-in-qt

Comment: can you be more spicified ?! @johnelemans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer supposing that you are asking (don't know if I understood well, since your question is hardly understandable) how to create a file one time, then later, write and read from this file already created.

First, you have to give your file a name.

```
QString fileName = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\file.txt";
QFile file(fileName);
```

- If your file is not already created : calling the function [QFile::open(OpenMode mode)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) **will create this file :**

  ```
  bool openOk = file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
  if (openOk)
  {
       // process
  }
  ```

  You can now write and read from your file.
- Later, if you want to use your file again, **just call this function again** : if the file is already created, then you can read/write in this file.