# Create log file in QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt

According [manual](https://evileg.com/en/post/154/) in order to log into file I need to open it in `main`:

```
QScopedPointer<QFile>   m_logFile;

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    m_logFile.reset(new QFile("logFile.txt"));
    // Открываем файл логирования

    m_logFile.data()->open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text);
    qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It works fine in case when I have created file. But how to create file if it not exist?

Comment: You need to ensure you use the `WriteOnly` or `ReadWrite` flags, as per: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new File with full path in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024382/how-to-create-a-new-file-with-full-path-in-qt)